# Magento2- Send custom transactional emails

Tags: magento2, transactional-mail

As done in Magento 1.x.x, how can custom transactional emails be sent.

***Additional***

- Add email in bcc
- Send attachment along email

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at Contact Module.

Comment: Yes I studied that and answered it below, for sharing purposes

Answer (score 10, accepted):

okie bit of debugging helps,

Sending a transactional email in Magento2

```
class Dummy
{

   /**
     * @var  \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    private $_transportBuilder;

  public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder){

    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
  }

  public function sendEmail($templateId =1, $storeId =1,$templateParams)
  {

     $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
            ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
            ->setTemplateVars($templateParams)
            ->setFrom('someemail@email.com')
            ->addTo('toemail@email.com')
            ->setReplyTo('replyto@email.com')
            ->addBcc('bcc@email.com')
            ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
  }

}
```

Comment: how to add subject in email template

Comment: @MagikVishal Your answer is here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/how-to-send-custom-email-no-template-in-magento2 `<!--@subject Promopoup@-->`

Comment: Doesn't work in Magento 2.1.2 anymore

Comment: @FredOroskoDias sure..will check and add ablock for 2.1.x as well..thanks

Comment: How do we add multiple BCC ?

Comment: did u try adding addBcc multiple times?

Comment: @Magento2Learner you can just use addBcc with an array as parameters.

Comment: Yes I tried but  mails are going just like normal mail not with BCC

Answer (score 0):

it's working for me

```
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTempVariables['myvar'] = $myvar;

$senderName = 'test';
$senderEmail = 'sender@test.com';
$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);
$sender = [
        'name' => $senderName,
        'email' => $senderEmail,
        ];

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template')
->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
->setFrom($sender)
->addTo($email)
->setReplyTo($senderEmail)            
->getTransport();               
$transport->sendMessage();
```

more info

[how to send custom email no template in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/how-to-send-custom-email-no-template-in-magento2)

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 Uses **\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder** class for send custom email.

You need to create a simple module and set **email_tempaltes.xml** file for defining your transaction mail templates.

You can send mail from Adminhtml or Frontend Scope area.

I have shared a link for step by step guide to send a custom mail from Magento 2 using a module.

[Send Custom Mail from Magento 2 Module](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/send-mail-from-custom-module-magento-2/)