# how to send custom email no template in magento2?

Tags: magento2, email

In magento2 send email with contact module  use:

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeScope))
                ->setTemplateOptions(
                    [
                        'area' => \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
                    ]
                )
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER, $storeScope))
                ->addTo($this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT, $storeScope))
                ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                ->getTransport();
$transport->sendMessage();
```

So i have create custom send email it not have template. but i don't know how do send email with transportBuilder is true.

this's data i want send.

```
$myData = Array ( 
   [to] => xxx@gmail.com 
   [email] => admin@gmail.com 
   [subject] => Magento Commerce
   [headers] => array(
            [reply_to] => admin@gmail.com
            )
   [body] => {{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
              {{depend Magento Commerce}} Magento Commerce {{/depend}}
                Name:   ABC
                Email:  abc@gmail.com
                Subject:    Magento Commerce
                Message:    Sample text.
            {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
 [type] => text/html
  [attachments] => 
)
```

How do i can send email with $myData use transportBuilder. Many thank!!

Answer (score 12):

You need to create `etc/email_templates.xml` add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="myemail_email_template" label="My Label" file="myemail.html" type="text" module="Modulename_Namespace" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

Now you need to add file in your module at **view/frontend/email/myemail.html**

```
<!--@subject Promopoup@-->
{{trans "My var: %myVar" myVar=$data.myvar}}
```

**myemail.html** is declared in **etc/email_templates.xml**

Now mail sending code as below:

```
                $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                $emailTempVariables['myvar'] = $myvar;

                $senderName = 'test';

                $senderEmail = 'sender@test.com';

                $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                $postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);

                $sender = [
                            'name' => $senderName,
                            'email' => $senderEmail,
                            ];

                $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($email)
                ->setReplyTo($senderEmail)            
                ->getTransport();               
                $transport->sendMessage();
```

Comment: thank a lot. i will try it tell you result

Comment: the mail sent empty

Comment: same issue .. its empty ... did you find any solution @MohammedGomma

Comment: @FredOroskoDias did you also get the empty email

Comment: @Adnan please check my answer below. Code which I post is working. If you have troubles on your side - install MailCatcher or MailHog and look what's happen. Also try simple php script with mail() function - maybe your sendmail isn't working :)

Comment: I got error: `Error filtering template: Warning: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/html/magento233/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Filter.php on line 703`

Comment: @Prashant, can we send email with the attachment? I like to send an email with csv file attached,

Comment: It doesn't do anything and no email is sent, any idea why?

Comment: Check logs and check email is working on you server or not

Answer (score 10):

Original question was about not using template (as I got it) but I'm not sure. Best practice I assume is to use email template.

Here is an example of my extension which sends emails every day (cronjob isn't included)

registration.php

```
<?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'ImaginationMedia_ReportSender',
        __DIR__
    );
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="ImaginationMedia_ReportSender" setup_version="1.1.0" />
</config>
```

etc/email_templates.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="daily_status_template"
              label="Daily Sales by ImaginationMedia"
              file="daily_status_template.html" type="html"
              module="ImaginationMedia_ReportSender" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="reportsender" frontName="reportsender">
            <module name="ImaginationMedia_ReportSender" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

view/frontend/email/daily_status_template.html

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Sales Report from Our Client"}} @-->

<h3>Report from {{var data.report_date|raw}}</h3>

<p><b>Number of orders:</b> {{var data.orders_count|raw}}</p>
<p><b>Items count:</b> {{var data.order_items_count|raw}}</p>
<p><b>Average items per order:</b> {{var data.avg_items|raw}}</p>
```

Model/ReportSend.php

```
<?php

    namespace ImaginationMedia\ReportSender\Model;

    use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;

    class ReportSend {

        public function __construct(
            TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ) {
            $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        }

        public function execute() {
            $report = [
                'report_date' => date("j F Y", strtotime('-1 day')),
                'orders_count' => rand(1, 10),
                'order_items_count' => rand(1, 10),
                'avg_items' => rand(1, 10)
            ];

            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($report);

            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('daily_status_template')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom(['name' => 'Robot','email' => 'robot@server.com'])
                ->addTo(['fred@server.com', 'otherguy@server.com'])
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
        }
    }
```

Controller/Adminhtml/ReportSender.php

```
<?php

    namespace ImaginationMedia\ReportSender\Controller\Adminhtml\ReportSender;

    use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
    use ImaginationMedia\ReportSender\Model\ReportSend;

    class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {

        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            ReportSend $reportSend
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->reportSend = $reportSend;
        }

        public function execute() {
            $this->reportSend->execute();
            echo 'Email sent!';
        }
    }
```

And finally to test sending your emails use this link (your security keys should be off for this trick):

```
http://yourwebsite.dev/admin/reportsender/reportsender/index
```

Comment: i am getting this error "Template file 'daily_status_template.html' is not found."

Comment: @sumeetbajaj check your `etc/email_templates.xml`, filename and path to it, and setTemplateIdentifier()

Comment: thanks for your reply,i solved my problem using this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/268608/magento-2-send-email-programatically-not-workingerror-template-file-name-of-fi?noredirect=1#comment381086_268608

Comment: thanks @FredOroskoDias it will very useful and simple steps