# How to send an email programmatically from a custom Order Confirmation Page- Magento 2 CE

Tags: php, email, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.7

I am attempting to send an email from my custom success.phtml file that will contain some needed information.

Everything else in the success file works except for the email part.

I have tried sending email with a template and without one.

The Order Confirmation Page is blank when I use the email code.

I am still a Magento newbie.

I have looked at and used other examples and code, and even the Magento 2 github ones, but obviously I don't understand what is missing.

I used the code from the answer of this post as a guide: 
[how to send custom email no template in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/how-to-send-custom-email-no-template-in-magento2)

Can anyone tell me what I need to change in my code?

This is what I have for my latest coding attempt:

In the web server, I made a file called *email_templates.xml* in 
/home/userName/public_html/mySite/app/etc/ .

In that *email_templates.xml* file I pasted the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="myemail_email_template" label="My Label" file="myemail.html" type="text" 

module="Modulename_Namespace" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

---

I then made a file called *myemail.html* in 
/home/userName/public_html/mySite/vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email

In that *myemail.htm*l file I pasted the code below:

```
<!--@subject Promopoup@-->
{{trans "My var: %myVar" myVar=$data.myvar}}
```

---

This is the email part that I pasted in my custom success.phtml file:

```
<?php

$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$emailTempVariables['myvar'] = $myvar;

$senderName = 'notARealName.com';

$senderEmail = 'notARealAddress@123.net';

$email = 'testemail@123.net';

$postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);

$sender = ['name' => $senderName,'email' => $senderEmail];

$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier('myemail_email_template')-

>setTemplateOptions(['area' =>\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,'store'=>

\Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom($sender)
                ->addTo($email)
                ->setReplyTo($senderEmail)            
                ->getTransport();               
                $transport->sendMessage();

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The code does not seem to be the problem, mostly  (except for the myemail.html file and the other code in the wrong folders ).  What is lacking is a module,  a registration file,  and a controller to send the email.  I will post a solution to this if I can ever get it right LW.  If anyone else has a solution, please feel free to chime in.

Comment: do you have any errors in the log?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
public function sendMailAction(){
$html="
put your html content here
blah blah

";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
$mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

try {
$mail->send();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
$this->_redirect('');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
$this->_redirect('');
}
}
?>
```

and you can get the sender email using

```
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
```

Comment: Is this for magento 2?

Comment: No, This is for magento one, let me edit it to make it magento 2

Comment: check this 2 links
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132391/how-to-send-mail-programmaticlly-in-magento2

https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/