# Send email from observer using smtp on magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, email, email-templates, smtp

I have this observer, and now i send emails via php mail() function, but i want to use the SMTP.
Can anyone tell me which steep i need to follow?

```
public function sendNotification($to,$subject,$products,$shippingAddress) 
    {       
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <example@mail.com>' . "\r\n";

        $message = '
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>Email notification</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Customer data</h1>
            <p>
                '.__('Name').$shippingAddress['firstname'].' '.$shippingAddress['lastname'].': <br />
                '.__('Phone').$shippingAddress['telephone'].': <br />
                '.__('Email').$shippingAddress['telephone'].': <br />
                '.__('Address').$shippingAddress['street'].' '.$shippingAddress['city'].' '.$shippingAddress['postcode'].' '.': <br />
            </p>
            <h2>Order details</h1>
            <table>
                '.$products.'
            </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
        mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }

    /* send email notification for both, rent & lend products */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();

        $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress(); // shipping address
        $customer = $order->getCustomerId(); // using this id you can get customer name

        $productsRent = '';
        $productsLend = '';
        /* parse all products list from the order */
        foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){ 
            $ProdustIds = $item->getProductId();
            $attribute_name = $this->getAttributeSetName($ProdustIds);

            if ($attribute_name=='rent') {
                $productName = $item->getName();
                $rent_price = $item->getData('rent_price');
                $rent_time = $item->getData('rent_time');

                $productsRent .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$productName.'</td>
                    <td>'.$rent_price.' '.$rent_time.'</td>
                </tr>';
            } elseif ($attribute_name=='lend') {
                $productName = $item->getName();

                $productsLend .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$productName.'</td>
                    <td>Gratis</td>
                    </tr>';
            } 
       }

       // send emails notification rent
       if($productsRent!='') {
            $this->sendNotification("example@mail.com","Rent email notification",$productsRent,$shippingAddress);
       }
```

Comment: is for magento 1. i am on magento 2

Comment: upps my fault that is for magento 1

Comment: you have to create template refer this surely for magento 2 ;) http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/124455/45103

Answer (score 0):

You can download free `smtp` extension of Magento 2. And send your custom email.

[magento2-gmailsmtpapp](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp)

Comment: i am using this extension but i am getting error Command not implemented