# Separate mail for customer and store(owner of store) for enquiry form

Tags: magento-2.1, email, contact-form

I have a new form named Service Request. When user submit a request I need to get separate  mail for both user and store.

The user content should be like   : Thanks You for contacting, Our team will assist you soon

The store content should contain the details that entered in form.

How can I achieve this....

Answer (score 0):

From `Magento 2` github page, you can download the `sample-module-newpage` extension using below link:

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-newpage
```

You can follow the below steps to complete your task:

1. Install `sample-module-newpage` extension
2. you can create `Service Request` form in the default template of extension
3. Create new controller for form post action. you can take reference from `Magento_Contact` module `Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post` controller.

4.you can use the below link to check how to send email in Magento 2:

```
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/how-to-send-custom-email-no-template-in-magento2
```

Hope this help !!