# Magento 2 send email programatically not working(error-Template file 'name_of_file.html' is not found.)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, email-templates

Magento 2 send email(adminhtml) programatically not working.
i am using this code -

```
$report = [
                'report_date' => date("j F Y", strtotime('-1 day')),
                'orders_count' => rand(1, 10),
                'order_items_count' => rand(1, 10),
                'avg_items' => rand(1, 10)
            ];

            $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
            $postObject->setData($report);

            $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier('sendcredentials')
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                ->setFrom(['name' => 'Robot','email' => 'robot@server.com'])
                ->addTo(['test@gmail.com', 'test@test.in'])
                ->getTransport();
            $transport->sendMessage();
```

and email_templates.xml(location-etc)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:Magento:module:Magento_Email:etc/email_templates.xsd">
    <template id="sendcredentials" label="Test email" file="sendcredentials.html" type="html" module="Vendor_Sendcredentials" area="adminhtml"/>
</config>
```

and HTML file sendcredentials.html(location-view/adminhtml/email) -

```
<!--@subject Custom @-->
<h3>Report from {{var data.report_date|raw}}</h3>

<p><b>Number of orders:</b> {{var data.orders_count|raw}}</p>
<p><b>Items count:</b> {{var data.order_items_count|raw}}</p>
<p><b>Average items per order:</b> {{var data.avg_items|raw}}</p>
```

I am getting this error -

**Template file 'sendcredentials.html' is not found.**

Comment: Which path you have the sendcredentials.html file?

Comment: It suppose to be in view/adminhtml/email/ folder, Please verify it

Comment: yes it is there,i commented my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my self,changed area

from

```
'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
```

to

```
'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML,
```