# Magento 2 Sending emails triggered by observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email

I'm trying to send emails using observer triggers, but I'm having problems with `_transportBuilder` (I can't get `TransportBuilder` instance).
I'm catching `customer_save_after_data_object` event and calling my custom class (it's working), but when I try to execute `$transport = $this->_transportBuilder...` I found issues.

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $vars = array();

    $transport = $this->_transportBuilder
        ->setTemplateIdentifier(1) // My email template
        ->setTemplateOptions( [
            'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, // this is using frontend area to get the template file if admin then \Magento\Backend\App\Area\FrontNameResolver::AREA_CODE
            'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID,
        ])
        ->setTemplateVars($vars)
        ->setFrom('test@test.com', 'Test')
        ->addTo('abc@def.com', 'Somepeople')
        ->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
}
```

---

**Result:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   **setTemplateIdentifier()** on null in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Company/mail/Observer/SendMail.php:62
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(73):
>   Company\mail\Observer\SendMail->execute(Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
>
> #1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(61):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->_callObserverMethod(Object(Company\mail\Observer\SendMail),
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
>
> #2
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php(66):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Invoker\InvokerDefault->dispatch(Array,
>   Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Observer))
>
> #3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php(95):
>   Magento\Framework\Event\Manager->dispatch('customer_save_a...', Array)
>
> #4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/mo in
>   /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/app/code/Company/mail/Observer/SendMail.php
>   on line 62

---

**Comments:**

I've tried to start setting "TemplateOptions" or "TemplateVars" and
 I've got the same problem. I believe the error is with the instance not found.

---

**Links (Questions followed):**

- [Magento2- Send custom transactional emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87940/magento2-send-custom-transactional-emails)
- [how to send custom email no template in magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124446/how-to-send-custom-email-no-template-in-magento2)

Comment: http://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having problems with `$transportBuilder` on `__construct()` and I removed all `var/generation/*` and compiled again and worked.

> rm -rf [MAGENTO_PATH]/var/generation/*

Comment: yes  sometimes it picks data from cache so you need to clear cache to see your changes.

Comment: @Gulshan Yes! You're right. But fortunately, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have just followed the first link you shared.
Please check their construct:

```
public function __construct( \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder){
    $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
}
```

You haven't created transbuilder instance so it was throwing error.
Please check and revert.

Comment: I did it! I found the problem.. The is with another thing... Thank you!

Comment: Welcome and happy coding. :)